# set json value from file to redis

Tags: json, bash, redis, redis-cli

I have a bash.sh script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

val=$(cat ../my-microservice/conf/config.json)

echo "set my-microservice-config ${val}" |  redis-cli
```

where the config.json:

```
{
  "key" : "value"
}
```

When I run it I got:

> ERR unknown command '}'

How to set a json value properly from the json file?

Comment: Do you need to store JSON as string, or `HASH`, native JSON, or something else?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are trying to set the [*string*](https://redis.io/topics/data-types) value of `my-microservice-config` key to the contents of your JSON file (or any other for that matter, including binary), the simplest approach is to use the [`-x` option in `redis-cli`](https://redis.io/topics/rediscli#getting-input-from-other-programs) to **read the last argument** of the command verbatim, **from `stdin`**. For example:

```
$ redis-cli -x set my-microservice-config < config.json
OK
```

For your example, this will store:

```
$ redis-cli get my-microservice-config
"{\n      \"key\" : \"value\"\n}\n"
```

To store the compact representation of your JSON data, you can use [`jq .` with  `-c`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) flag:

```
$ jq -c . config.json | redis-cli -x set my-microservice-config
OK
$ redis-cli get my-microservice-config
"{\"key\":\"value\"}\n"
```

Note that Redis does not natively support JSON, but there's the [ReJSON module](https://github.com/redislabsmodules/rejson) you can use if you need [interpreted JSON values](https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-as-a-json-store/) (JSON datatype).

Comment: thx. related in addition: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382769/vertx-config-redis-wrongtype-operation-against-a-key-holding-the-wrong-kind-of

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use quotes on the value as it contains spaces - change the last line of your script to:

```
echo "set my-microservice-config \"${val}\"" |  redis-cli
```

Comment: This doesn't work when `val` contains `\n` (try the OP's example). One option is to use `jq -c` to reformat the JSON file, but `-x` option of `redis-cli` can handle *any binary* data (including `NUL`s, which shell variables can never handle).

Comment: @randomir good point, and I do prefer your `-x` answer (I was the 1st upvote btw). However, the OP's core problem with the script was the lack of quotes so I felt compelled to point it out :)

Comment: Actually, I suggested quotes in the first draft of my answer (you can check the edits), but then realized they aren't reliable enough for handling custom JSON. :) BTW, nice work on `rejson` module! :)

Comment: thx. related in addition: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382769/vertx-config-redis-wrongtype-operation-against-a-key-holding-the-wrong-kind-of