# vertx-config & redis WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

Tags: java, redis, vert.x

In redis-cli:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get my-microservice-config
"{\n "http.port": 35001\n}\n"
```

(the way I set it is [from the bash-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368364/set-json-value-from-file-to-redis): `redis-cli -x set my-config < my-microservice-config.json` ) where the my-microservice-config.json hold the json configuration.

In the code where I use `vertx-config`:

```
final ConfigStoreOptions redisSore = new ConfigStoreOptions()
.setType("redis")
.setConfig(new JsonObject()
.put("host", "localhost")
.put("port", 6379)
.put("key", "my-microservice-config")
);

final ConfigRetriever retriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx, options);
retriever.getConfig( ar -> {
if ( ar.failed()) {
System.out.println("Failed to retrieve the configuration");
```

...

got error:

> WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

checking the type of the value: it looks pretty much like **string type**

```
127.0.0.1:6379> type my-microservice-config
string
```

but anyways.. **the question is**: how to retrieve the config value that I see in cli when I do get ?

Comment: well I see now why: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-config/blob/master/vertx-config-redis/src/main/java/io/vertx/config/redis/RedisConfigStore.java

Comment: hgetall my-microservice-config (error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value. I can not say it is nice though. I would love to get my json as I set it.